# When and how to use asyncio queues?

Tags: python-asyncio, fastapi

I have multiple api routes which return data by querying database individually.

Now I'm trying to build dashboard which queries above api's. How should I put api calls in the queue so that they are executed asynchronously?

I tried

`await queue.put({'response_1': await api_1(**kwargs), 'response_2': await api_2(**kwargs)})`

It seems as though data is returned while task is being put in the queue.

Now I'm using

`await queue.put(('response_1', api_1(**args_dict)))`

in producer and in consumer I'm parsing tuple and making api calls which I think I'm doing wrong .

**Question1**
Is there a better way to do it?

This is code I'm using to create tasks

```
producers = [create_task(producer(**args_dict, queue)) for row in stats]
consumers = [create_task(consumer(queue)) for row in stats]
await gather(*producers)
await queue.join()
for con in consumers:
    con.cancel()
```

**Question2** Should I use create_task or ensure_future? Sorry if it's repetitive but I can't understand the difference and after searching online I became more confused.

I'm using FastAPI, databases(async) packages.

I'm using tuple instead of dictionary like await queue.put('response_1', api_1(**kwargs))

```
./app/dashboard.py:90: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'api_1' was never awaited
item: Tuple = await queue.get_nowait()
```

My code for consumer is

```
async def consumer(return_obj: dict, que: Queue):
    item: Tuple = await queue.get_nowait()
    print(f'consumer took {item[0]} from queue')
    return_obj.update({f'{item[0]}': await item[1]})
    await queue.task_done()
```

if I don't use get_nowait consumer gets stuck because queue may be empty,
but if I use get_nowait above error is shown. 
I haven't defined max queue length

**-----------EDIT-----------**

Producer

```
async def producer(queue: Queue, **kwargs):
    await queue.put('response_1', api_1(**kwargs))
```

Comment: Your edited code doesn't look runnable because `put` accepts only one argument, and you appear to be giving it two. Please provide actual code and, if possible, a minimal but runnable example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I've added producer which uses tuple object where 1st element is the **key** and 2nd element is **coroutine** @ user4815162342

Comment: That is not what the code in the question shows, though - I guess it is missing a pair of parentheses. Details matter in these things, and it is best to provide a runnable example in order to get help.

Answer (score 1):

You can drop the `await` from your first snippet and send the *coroutine object* in the queue. A coroutine object is a coroutine that was called, but not yet awaited.

```py
# producer:
await queue.put({'response_1': api_1(**kwargs),
                 'response_2': api_2(**kwargs)})
...

# consumer:
while True:
    dct = await queue.get()
    for name, api_coro in dct:
        result = await api_coro
        print('result of', name, ':', result)
```

> Should I use `create_task` or `ensure_future`?

If the argument is the result of invoking a coroutine function, you should use `create_task` (see [this comment](https://github.com/python/asyncio/issues/477#issuecomment-268709555) by Guido for explanation). As the name implies, it will return a `Task` instance that drives that coroutine. The task can also be awaited, but it continues to run in the background.

`ensure_future` is a much more specialized function that converts various kinds of awaitable objects to their corresponding futures. It is useful when *implementing* functions like `asyncio.gather()` which accept different kinds of awaitable objects for convenients, and need to convert them into futures before working with them.